# OpenGL rectangle resizes by one pixel arbitarily when moving

Tags: opengl, animation

I am having drawn a small 2D rectangle outline in OpenGL with GL_LINE_LOOP--very standard stuff as provided by numerous tutorials. The rectangle is being not rotated in space with its axis aligned to the screen. I have call to glTranslatef(x, y) to get my rectangle moving across the screen. The Vertex coordinates are a constant fraction of the screen width and screen height.

When the rectangle moves very slowly, I notice that the lower or upper boundary may move a little bit earlier than the border of the rectangle across, which follows immediately after. This is only a pixel and for a split second but makes the animation looks ugly.

It doesn't matter if antialias is on or off, although if antialias is on, the line temporarily appears to double (or thicken).

I was wondering if this is standard in OpenGL and if there is a command I am missing to avoid a mini-resizing when animating the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, this is most likely your problem:

> The Vertex coordinates are a constant fraction of the screen width and screen height.

These coordinates are in theory exactly on the boundary between two pixels. Because of floating point inaccuracy, the result is that the vertex can end up inside either one of two neighboring pixels.

To make the explanation simple, say your window has a width of 20 pixels, and you use NDC (normalized device coordinates) to specify your vertices. So the coordinate range is [-1.0, 1.0]. Dividing the range of 2.0 coordinate units into 20 pixels means that each pixel is 0.1 units wide. The coordinate ranges covered by each pixel are then:

```
[-1.0, -0.9], [-0.9, -0.8], [-0.8, -0.7], ... , [0.8, 0.9], [0.9, 1.0]
```

So if you use coordinates that are fractions of the pixel count, like -0.8, that coordinate is on the boundary between two pixels.

If you want pixel accurate drawing, you will have much more success by using coordinates that are in the center of a pixel. In the example above, you would use the following coordinates to address each pixel:

```
-0.95, -0.85, -0.75, ... , 0.85, 0.95
```

In general, if your range of coordinates if from `xMin` to `xMax`, and you have `n` pixels within that range, the center coordinate of pixel `k` is:

```
xMin + ((k + 0.5) / n) * (xMax - xMin)
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought of solving it in a similar way, but I was hoping that OpenGL would have something inbuilt to prevent this from happening.